# Any dual quad transparent latches?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit

I have a project where I need to load a stream of 4-bit parallel data into a 32 "register" (the latch). I am wondering if there are any ICs that contain two 4-bit transparent latches? This would cut component count in half, compared to, say, 74HC373.

Inputs to the register are a sequence of 8 4-bit nybbles at 3.3V CMOS logic levels, clocked at ~80 MHz. The clock is configurable; either rising- or falling-edge latch is acceptable. Output must be a single 32-bit wide word at 3.3V CMOS logic levels, latched at ~10 MHz (80÷8) (a separate, synchronous ~10 MHz clock is available). The 32-bit output must be held valid for at least 2/3 of the ~10 MHz clock cycle; no visible bit-shifting should appear on this output. Output tri-state / high-z is not necessary.

Low cost is a goal; the solution should ideally be less than $5 to implement (based on e.g. Mouser qty 10 to qty 100 component pricing).

Comment: How about SN74ALS873? (3.3 V? Goodbye, ALS) Wait, if it's 8 nibbles serially, pin count will be smaller using 4 8-bit SIPOs.

Comment: CD4508B looks like another one, not sure if its fast enough.

Comment: @greybeard SIPOs are a good idea, thanks.

Comment: @greybeard for the SIPO approach, 74LVC595A looks fast and cheap.

Comment: If you want a formal answer, please state available inputs and required outputs in the question. In particular: Do you need outputs (4 or 32 out of 32?) to follow inputs *without clock edge*, at one of the clock *levels*? Otherwise, you may be free to choose registers or latches. Any requirements beyond 3.3 V? (The 595 as the 4094 has an output latch, which may bee boon or burden. There are, of course, SIPOs without extra latch. There are PLDs, microcontrollers ...)

Answer (score 1):

That should be quite a ride to implement with transparent latches.
(Being surprised by the (low) \$f_{MAX}\$ of more than one SIPO, I tried to find a contemporary \$f_{MAX}\$ for quad transparent latches without success.)

On the other hand, using four 8-bit SIPO registers with output latch should work.
80 MHz is high enough at 3.3 V to need a keen eye on device specs, decoupling & layout.

Comment: (Just thought that for hand layout, I might prefer "parallel latches" over SIPOs.)